# How many relatively prime 4-tuples are there?

Tags: combinatorics

Given a set of $n$ distinct integers $S = \{a_1,a_2,...., a_n\}$, count how many ways $4$ integers from the set $S$ can be chosen such that their GCD is equal to $1$.

Comment: What if all the integers were prime numbers? What if all the integers were even?

Comment: yes i am looking for an algorithm to determine the number

Comment: The most obvious algorithm is to enumerate all $4$-tuples and count the ones that have gcd $1$.  Are you looking for something more efficient?

Comment: i encountered the problem from http://e-maxx.ru/algo/inclusion_exclusion_principle...                              originally this page is in Russian and the google translation was not clear.......i am wondering how to solve the problem using Principle of Inclusion-exclusion.......any other solution is also welcomed

Comment: Well there are nx(n-1)x(n-2) ways to choose the first three terms a_i, a_j, a_k and there are utterly no restrictions on what those can be so you have to count them all.  Figure gcd(a_i,a_j,a_k)= V and count the remaining n- k terms a_l such that gcd(a_l, V) = 1.  As any three terms can be the first three terms I don't see that there is any greater efficiency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a reinterpretation of the Google translation of the relevant section of that page (http://e-maxx.ru/algo/inclusion_exclusion_principle):

We solve the inverse problem—count the number of "bad" quadruples, i.e. quadruples in which all the numbers are divisible by some $d > 1$.

We use the inclusion-exclusion formula, adding the number of quadruples, dividing by the divisor d(but possibly divisible, and a larger divisor):

$$\text{# of bad quadruples} = \sum_{d \geq 2} (-1)^{\text{deg}(d) -1} \cdot f(d),$$

where $\text{deg}(d)$ is the number of prime divisors of $d$ and $f(d)$ is the number of quadruples divisible by d.

To calculate $f(d)$, you simply count the number of multiples of $d$, and use the binomial coefficient to count the number of ways to choose a set of four of them.

Thus, this formula counts the number of quadruples divisible by a prime, and then subtract the number of quadruples that are divisible by the product of two primes, add the number of quadruples divisible by three primes, etc.

Comment: i don't understand how number of bad quadruples is equal to that expression

Comment: The last sentence explains intuitively why that is the case. You want to count all quadruples that share a common factor, but each quadruple should count only once. So you first count all with one prime factor, then subtract the ones that have two prime factors (since you counted them twice before) then add back the ones that have three prime factors (since you subtracted them twice in the last step), and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you know the set $P$ of primes that divide $a_1 a_2 \ldots a_n$.  Let $M(t)$ be the number of elements of $S$ divisible by $t$.  Note that the number of (unordered) $4$-tuples from $S$ that are all divisible by $t$ is ${M(t) \choose 4}$.  Then your answer is
$$ \sum_{A \subseteq P} (-1)^{|A|} {M(\prod A) \choose 4}$$
where $\prod A$ is the product of the primes in $A$.

For example, if $S = \{1,2,\ldots, 12\}$, $P = \{2,3,5,7,11\}$, but the only cases where $M(\prod A) \ge 4$ are $$\matrix{A = \emptyset, & M(1) = 12\cr
A = \{2\}, & M(2) = 6\cr A = \{3\}, & M(3) = 4}$$
and so your answer is $${12 \choose 4} - {6 \choose 4} - {4 \choose 4} = 479$$

This will **not** be an efficient algorithm in general: besides the difficulty of factoring, there may be lots of primes, and a huge number of subsets of these primes to consider.